# Get the latest UUID created in django model

Tags: django

i want to get the id of the latest entry in a django model, i m using UUID and this query is not working for me it is giving me another id of a fields submitted before that is by some comparaison the biggest.

```js
 Uploads.objects.latest('id')
```

Comment: UUIDs have no ordering, so you must use another field that does have an order.

Comment: yeah i m getting the last one by the creation date, thanks for responding

Answer (score 1):

add `created_at` field to `User` model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    # ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    # ...
```

then you can get latest user like this:

```
Uploads.objects.latest('created_at')
```

**P.s:** Django `User` model also has a field called `date_joined` so maybe you don't need to add `created_at` to your model.

```
# in AbstractUser source code
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
```